# Facebook User Authorization to use an application

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I have a .net website and I want to post messages by the facebook api to every user's wall.I want via an application to post messages, but the error message when i execute Stream.Publish is "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".
I am using the Facebook Developer Toolkit. I believe that i make something wrong in the configuration of the settings of my facebook application but I am not sure.

Comment: I haven't programmed against the API, but I've used Facebook. A user must explicitly grant any application access to their wall and profile before that application can manipulate or post anything therein.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [samples](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/39727) It may help you understand if you do something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following this in the Page_PreInit() event

base.RequiredPermissions = new List();

base.RequiredPermissions.Add(Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream);

base.RequireLogin = true;

or use

Response.Redirect("http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + **ApiKey** + "&next=http://apps.facebook.com/**yourapplication**/&display=page&locale=en_US&return_session=0&fbconnect=0&canvas=1&legacy_return=1&req_perms=publish_stream");